# Is it possible to copy an entire project using the Project Server 2016 REST API?

Tags: rest, 2016, project-server, pwa

Is it possible to copy an entire project via the Project Server REST API?  Something similar to what would happen if you opened a project (from the server) using Project Pro, and then did "Save As" and saved it with a new name (back to the server)?

Even more specifically, will it preserve links between a master schedule and sub-projects?

I have seen this behavior with the Project Pro desktop client:

Say you had a master schedule with two sub-projects.  If you open all three projects simultaneously in Project Pro, then "Save As" to rename the sub-projects, you can see that the master schedule is automatically updated to link to the new copies of the sub-projects.  If you then "Save As" to create a copy of the master schedule, the new copy gets saved with references to the new versions of the sub-projects, but if you then go back into the original master schedule, it is still referencing the original versions of the sub-projects.

So now you have essentially created a "snapshot" of the entire project, preserving the links between the master and sub-projects, and preserving any links between any tasks within those projects.

Can you do something like that via REST?  I know from [another question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/40f34e5f-8139-445b-ab70-bb5cfcae916b/how-do-you-insert-a-project-as-a-subproject-using-the-2016-rest-api?forum=project2010custprog) that you can't directly link a sub-project to a master schedule, but can you somehow "check out" multiple projects and then re-save them as copies with new names, and have the existing links be preserved (and updated to reflect linking to the new copy of the project) in the same way?

I have been trying to comb through the [MSDN documentation on the Project Server REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj669214.aspx#Anchor_2), but I have not seen anything like "copy" or some equivalent to "save as", all I have seen is that you can change the name of the project (without creating a copy).